# How to redirect stderr to stdout then pipe (apt-cache)

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection, file-descriptors

I'm trying to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` and then `pipe` it but I think I'm missing something basic here.

The command and output to be piped:

```
$ apt-cache show contractor
N: Can't select versions from package 'contractor' as it is purely virtual
N: No packages found
```

Grep does not work - must be outputting to `stderr`:

```
$ apt-cache show contractor |grep virtual
```

OK Let's redirect `stderr` to `stdout`:

```
$ apt-cache show contractor 2>&1 |grep virtual
```

**Nope this does not work, why?**

Confirm which file descriptor the command is using:

```
$ apt-cache show contractor 1>t ;cat t

$ apt-cache show contractor 2>t ;cat t
N: Can't select versions from package 'contractor' as it is purely virtual
N: No packages found
```

Confirmed it's using `stderr`.

Something to do with ordering of redirects?

```
$ apt-cache show contractor |cat 2>&1
```

Nope

```
$ apt-cache show contractor 2>&1 |cat 2>&1
```

Nope

How to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` then `pipe`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `apt-cache` will become "quiet" and not print those lines when its stdout is not a tty.

You can override that determination by setting its "quietness" to 0:

```
$ apt-cache -q=0 show contractor 2>&1 | grep virtual
N: Can't select versions from package 'contractor' as it is purely virtual
```